# Create PyOpenCL Context in Blender 2.65 BGE

Tags: blender, pyopencl

How can I create Context in Blender BGE (python3.3) with gl interop?
When I use this way

```
from OpenGL import platform as gl_platform
        ctx_props = cl.context_properties
        props = []
        if sys.platform == "linux":
            from OpenGL import GLX
            props.append((ctx_props.PLATFORM, self.platform))
            props.append((ctx_props.GL_CONTEXT_KHR, GLX.glXGetCurrentContext()))
            props.append((ctx_props.GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, GLX.glXGetCurrentDisplay()))
        elif sys.platform == "win32":
            from OpenGL import WGL
            props.append((ctx_props.PLATFORM, self.platform))
            props.append((ctx_props.GL_CONTEXT_KHR, gl_platform.GetCurrentContext()))
            props.append((ctx_props.WGL_HDC_KHR, WGL.wglGetCurrentDC()))
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":
            props.append((ctx_props.CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE, cl.get_apple_cgl_share_group()))

if sys.platform == "darwin":
            ctx = cl.Context(properties=props, devices=[])
        else:
            try:
                ctx = cl.Context(properties=props)
            except:
                ctx = cl.Context(properties=props, devices = [device])
```

Blender crashed.
I use Blender 2.65 & pyopencl form git. Ubuntu 12.10.